# Socket connection failed after a long time of waiting

Tags: java, sockets

What are some reasons why a socket connection would fail with a given ip and port? Is there a way to fix this? On some occasion i would get a socket connection failure. But I would only find out after waiting for a few minutes. Is there a way to find out if a connection would fail in a shorter amount of time?

```
try{
        socketConn = new Socket(this.ip, this.port);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Failed creating a Socket Connection in Peer constructor for " +id +
                " with IP: " +ip+" and on port: "+port);

    }
```

Comment: You can reduce your time-out duration, but this can cause connections which might have connected to fail.

Comment: What does the exception tell you?

Comment: are you sure there's someone listening on that ip/port?

Comment: @yair If there wasn't he would get 'connection refused', not a timeout. This is a connectivity problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an unconnected `Socket` and supply a `SocketAddress` with a `long` timeout value on its the `connect()` method.

Its actually pretty important that you set this or your connect operation will block(by default) for an indefinite amount of time

[Socket Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

Comment: It won't block for 'an indefinite amount of time', it will block for about 70-75 seconds depending on the platform.

Comment: @EJP oh so you mean like...an undefined amount time that is completely platform dependent my bad I meant to say...indefinite?

Answer (score 0):

connection time out often occurs for slow response of server. check the net connection and server .